# How to make BOTH windows title and menu always visible on maximized windows (unity)?

Tags: unity, google-chrome, window-manager, window, application-switcher

In Unity settings there are 2 options for Menú visibility:

- Display on mouse over
- Always displayed

If I select the first the title of the window is always visible on top but the menu is not until I hover: I think this is really bad UX. The menu should be always visible I shouldn't have to hover the mouse to see it. I want to go directly to the right spot and click not move generically in the area and wait for the menu to appear to actually move the cursor where I need.

If I set the second option I find it really annoying that windows title is not shown at all, only the menu is visible.

[image: Screenshot, window title not showing]

Some software show important information in the window title (like, in this case, the project name I'm looking at) so that I can say, at first glance, in which window I'm in.

Unity doesn't show the title when the window is maximized. Same goes for windows having menu in there. (Example chrome: windows title is supposed to show the current tab title).

The same things happens, even if less annoying on the default switcher: only the highlighted window shown the title, the other ones do not show it and you have to hover the mouse to see the title.

[image: Switcher screen not showing title]

How do I make Ubuntu Unity always show BOTH the title and the menu of the windows?

Answer (score 0):

that is strange, normal behaviour should be like you want it. Unity shows the menu for a specified time after you start the app and than it should show the app title...

Comment: This is also not acceptable in my opinion, but no it's not how it happen. The title should ALWAYS be in the middle, right to the menu. Maybe I enabled some option to make the menu stay there always . The menu shouldn't disappear it's just really bad UX.

Comment: I've updated my question. I forgot about that setting